# when i create a jar file it shows some jdbc errors

Tags: java

I created a project using NetBeans IDE, using MySQL as back end. The project runs without single error when I execute in NetBeans but when I convert it into JAR file it is showing driver errors while connecting to database.

Screenshot of the error:
[image: the error is below]

Please anyone help me with this.

Comment: Make sure your JDBC jar is included in the bundle. Import your jar file in netbeans and see if you can find MySQL JDBC in lib folder.

Comment: How do you register your driver?

Comment: I included MYSQL JDBC in the lib .It shows no errors when i execute it in netbeans .when i created jar file and executed then only it is showing driver errors

Comment: Include the error message as a string in your question and not as an image. Text is searchable, images are not.

Comment: Rebuild your jar with JDBC driver jar included this time.

Answer (score 0):

It happens with me long days ago and it was a jar bundling issue. Kindly check following stuff

1. Is created jar contains mysql odbc jar or mysql odbc classes?
2. If not then add a target tag in build.xml which is available in the root folder as mentioned in http://arunasujith.blogspot.com/2011/08/how-to-build-fat-jar-using-netbeans.html

Hope It works for you.